# Как с помощью jquery переместить элемент при определённом разрешении экрана

Tags: jquery

```js
$(window).resize(function() {
  if($(window).width() < 992) {
    $('.logo').append($('.logo1'));
  }
  else{
    $('.logo1').appendTo($('body'));
  }
});
```

```css
.logo{
  background: #ccc;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}

.logo1{
  background: #444;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="logo">  
</div>

<div class="logo1">
</div>
```

При поиске в интернете находил очень много вариантов, пробовал, но все они какие-то "костыли" что ли были. Меня интересует как это сделать наиболее правильно и универсально для любой ситуации с помощью jquery.

Comment: Можно создать два элемента и скрывать через media query.

Answer (score 2):

В `jquery` есть `resize` событие который срабатывает при изменении размера окна. Вот пример кода, не знаю что в нем объяснить? Вроде все элементарно.

```js
$(window).resize(function(){
  if($(window).width < 700){
    $('.block-2').append($('.inner'));
  }
});
$(document).ready(function(){
  if($(window).width < 700){
    $('.block-2').append($('.inner'));
  }
});
```

```css
.block-1{
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
}
.block-2{
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="block-1">
   <div class="inner">
      Лорэм ипсум
   </div>
</div>

<div class="block-2">
</div>
```

Comment: Но насколько я понимаю, он не сработает, если я, допустим, сразу открою сайт на маленьком устройстве?

Comment: @Kellok Внес изменение, сейчас сработает.

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ.

Comment: Почему-то блок начинает "скакать" туда-сюда, при достижении значения экрана близкого к 992, а потом успокаивается. Почему так происходит? p.s. обновил код, но тут он почему-то вообще не работает.

Comment: Понял в чем была проблема - полоса прокрутки, то добавлялась, то убиралась.

Answer (score 2):

Вот так еще проще и кстати, вот ссылка на JSFiddle, так как там можно уменьшать размер фрейма https://jsfiddle.net/bq04yot4/:

```js
    function resizeBlock(){
     if(window.matchMedia("screen and (max-width: 992px)").matches) {
        $('.logo').append($('.logo1'));
      }
      else if (window.matchMedia("screen and (min-width: 992px)").matches){
        $('.logo1').appendTo($('body'));
      }
    }
    
    $(window).resize(function() {
         resizeBlock();
    });
    
    $(document).ready(function(){
        resizeBlock();
     });
```

```css
.logo{
  background: #ccc;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}

.logo1{
  background: #444;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="logo">  
</div>

<div class="logo1">
</div>
```